# how we can parse proto file if it having "." and "-" sign

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java, grpc-python, protobuf-java

I create one proto file using java and another using python when I put "." and "-" sign in proto file message field name it shows error that is "missing field number". I m not able to parse that file. and if proto file not accept this character please can share list of character which proto file not accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the [protobuf documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#simple) on proper syntax for defining messages in protos.

`.` is used for selecting an attribute of an object in python, so obviously one shouldn't use it in message fields of proto. Instead You can use `_` as character for separating words in a single field name.

A small Sample for you :

```
syntax = "proto3";

message SearchRequest {
  string query = 1;
  int32 page_number = 2;
  int32 result_per_page = 3;
}
```